# Repeat element from list

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In a makefile is there any way to specifiy the same element of a list (I think this is the correct term) more than once? For example, having a a list with 3 files `A.txt B.txt C.txt`, I'd like to create targets based on these elements that would be contained within a directory where the pattern would have to be repeated twice: `A/A-rambo B/B-rambo C/C-rambo`.

I tried:

```
TXT = A.txt B.txt C.txt

DIR := $(patsubst %.txt,%,$(TXT))
OUT := $(patsubst %,%/%-rambo,$(DIR))

$(info $(OUT))
```

but this prints `A/%-rambo B/%-rambo C/%-rambo`, where the second `%`is not being replaced.

And so does `OUT := $(patsubst %,$(addsuffix /%-rambo,%),$(DIR))`

Comment: Do you want to create *rules* for those targets? Normal rules, or a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro), or a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern), or what?

Comment: I'd then like to create a pattern rule, so each file in `OUT` is created in a rule that uses the corresponding `TXT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make cannot handle a pattern rule with two wildcards in the target name, even if they're required to have the same value.

There's more than one way to get the effect you want, none ideal. I'd suggest generating a rule for each `txt` file:

```
define template
$(1)/$(1)-rambo: $(1).txt
        @echo building $$@ from $$^
endef

STEMS := A B C
$(foreach x,$(STEMS),$(eval $(call template,$(x))))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be iterating ver all `STEMS`; I'm just getting one printed line: `building A/A-rambo from A.txt`, correctly, but the others for `B` and `C` are missing.

Comment: @PedroA: "Missing"? I suspect that are simply not invoking the other two rules. Try `make B/B-rambo` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
OUT := $(foreach T,$(TXT),$(T:.txt=)/$(T:.txt=-rambo))
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but then I can't make a target of it: `./make:10: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "can't make a target of it".  Nothing in your question shows any targets.  What are you trying to do?